# how to test a angular service which named as 'sample.Svc' in my modules using mocha+chai

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mocha.js, naming, karma-mocha

My service file service.js

```
angular.module('services', [])
  .service('sample.Svc', ['$window', 'modalSvc', function($window, modalSvc){
    this.showDialog = function(message, title){
      console.log(" in here");
      if(title){
        modalSvc.showModalDialog({
          title: title,
          message: message
        });
      } else {
        $window.alert(message);
      }
    };
  }]);
```

My serviceSpec.js

```
describe('service tests', function(){
  var mockWindow, mockModalSvc, sampleSvcObj;
  beforeEach(function(){
    module(function($provide){
      $provide.service('$window', function(){
        this.alert = sinon.spy();
      });
      $provide.service('modalSvc', function(){
        this.showModalDialog = sinon.spy();
      });
    });
    module('services');
  });
  beforeEach(inject(function($window, modalSvc, sample.Svc){
    mockWindow=$window;
    mockModalSvc=modalSvc;
    sampleSvcObj=sampleSvc;
  }));
 it('Need to pass', function() {
        expect(false).to.be.false;
    });
});
```

While running my `serviceSpec.js` (using Karma)
I am getting error like

> "SyntaxError: Parse error".

I know this error caused due to the argument name(sample.Svc) with '`.`'. But I dont know other ways to use my service "`sample.Svc`" in my testcases. Some body help me to inject my service in any other way.

Services are named by using dot by others, I have permission to change them. So I need some solution with same naming structure.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using best practices for naming conventions. You will save a lot of time and headaches

https://github.com/mgechev/angularjs-style-guide#services

Edit: to elaborate, call your service "Sample" or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, But I have to follow the same naming conventions as I told earlier.